# Zend Framework - how to copy variables from one view to another

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

I need to pass variables dynamically to another view.

Like array_merge() function does, but it only accepts arrays.

Thanks. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `getVars()` function on the source view to get an array, and then you could just set the values on the target view.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get a be a little more specific? If you've got an array of variables you want loaded into a view, you can do this:

```
foreach ($varArray as $k => $v) {
    $myView->assign($k, $v);
}
```

I don't think that quite answers your question though.

Comment: I have two $views. $myView1 and $myView2

Comment: $view->assign can take array as well as parameter ;)

Answer (score 0):

I woud use registry. It's simple and works. Even if it's like globals ;)